# Storage Table - REST and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-table-storage

Maybe the question is stupid but I do it anyway :)

I would like to write into a azure storage table by client side (JavaScript), is that possible?

Comment: I think I answered a similar question on MSDN Forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/ea314c8b-d6bf-4111-b854-fb2ffbbaccc8/tables-insert-an-item-with-javascript-by-rest-api#203656d5-1829-42b1-aab0-b018d2ea471d. The answer is still "not yet" :)

Comment: OMG Gaurav do you answer everywhere ? :D
Ok that was a double check.

Comment: LOL! I'm also eagerly waiting for this feature (+ JSON support). Hopefully it should be soon.

Comment: And a JSONP framework? or a solution about a cross domain call

Comment: Not sure about JSONP. JSON mainly for smaller payloads and response bodies. Cross domain call issue should be resolved once CORS support is in place.

Answer (score 1):

Right now my workaround is to write services in Java/Jersey that talk to Azure table services. Jersey supports CORS so I can access the services through javascript easily.

The big problem with accessing any REST service from Javascript is security. It should be okay for public services though.

Answer (score 1):

At the BUILD conference, Windows Azure Storage announced support for JSON and CORS coming by the end of 2013. This will make it easy to access your table storage account directly from JavaScript code to read and write data.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/06/28/windows-azure-storage-build-talk-what-s-coming-best-practices-and-internals.aspx

In the meantime, you can create a small web service that you call from your JavaScript code to access your table storage account.